# Why isn't the sticky bud plant more widespread

Tags: botany

Why isn't the sticky bud plant (Galium aparine) everywhere around the world? Because to me it seems that it has the best method of seed dispersion/transportation (wiki link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galium_aparine)

Comment: Can you link up something on the "sticky bud" plant?  I would like to read more about it.  I suspect there may be more than one plant with sticky buds.

Comment: Cleavers are distributed all over the world. The link you provide answers the question. (They shouldn't be able to grow in the desert.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already pointed out in comments, *Galium aparine* is actually very widespread, according to [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galium_aparine) it occurs in "a wide region of Europe, North Africa and Asia from Britain and the Canary Islands to Japan. It is now naturalized throughout most of the United States, Canada, Mexico, Central America, South America, Australia, New Zealand, some oceanic islands and scattered locations in Africa."
Because it occurs on moist and rich soils, it doesn't occur everywhere. It is unable to grow on dry and nutrient-poor soils (like deserts and steppes). But it is also absent in frequently mown grassland.